# AWK script doesn't print last column of CSV file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have the following awk script:

```
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","; } 
{ print $4,$1,$2; }
```

and this is my input file:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4
b1,b2,b3,b4
```

I'd expect it to return:

```
a4,a1,a2
b4,b1,b2
```

But it doesn't. Instead I get:

```
,a1,a2
,b1,b2
```

Why is that?

Comment: Most likely your input file has DOS line feeds.  This is a massive FAQ; see the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Look at the data you have and confirm if its really the same as pasted.

Comment: Agree with @AvinashRaj - I get the right output.

Comment: use `dos2unix inputfile` to fix the file.

Comment: Indeed: it was a CR/LF windows line ending which snuck in there through copy-pasting.

And here I am, wondering for two days what is going on..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely it is due to `DOS` line ending `\r` at the end of each line. Use this `gnu-awk` command to get the right output:

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n' 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } { print $4,$1,$2 }' file
a4,a1,a2
b4,b1,b2
```